# Docker in docker Gitlab Runner Privileged services problem

Tags: docker, ssl, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to use my self-hosted gitlab runner which has the following configuration in /etc/gitlab-runnner/config.toml

```bash
name = "docker"
url = "https://gitlab.self.hosted.com"
id = 6
token = "my_token"
token_obtained_at = 2023-07-04T10:11:42Z
token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
executor = "docker"
[runners.cache]
 MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
[runners.docker]
 tls_verify = false
 image = "docker:24.0.2"
 privileged = true
 disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
 oom_kill_disable = false
 disable_cache = false
 volumes = ["/certs/client", "/cache"]
 shm_size = 0
```

I have created a very simple pipeline that for now just prints out the docker info to know if the configuration is valid or not:

```yaml
stages: # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - test  
test-job: # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  stage: test
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - name: registry.hub.docker.com/library/docker:24.0.2-dind
      alias: docker
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376/
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: '/certs'
  tags: [docker]
  script:
    - docker info
```

So with this configuration, it works fine with the cert created by docker.

But as read in the doc, you can limit the privileged = true given to your runner, see on [this link.](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#use-rootless-docker-in-docker-with-restricted-privileged-mode)

So following the doc, my config.toml became:

```bash
name = "docker"
url = "https://gitlab.self.hosted.com"
id = 6
token = "my_token"
token_obtained_at = 2023-07-04T10:11:42Z
token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
executor = "docker"
[runners.cache]
  MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
[runners.docker]
  tls_verify = false
  image = "docker:24.0.2"
  services_privileged = true
  allowed_privileged_services = ["docker.io/library/docker:*-dind-rootless", "docker.io/library/docker:dind-rootless", "docker:*-dind-rootless", "docker:*-dind-rootless"]
  disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
  oom_kill_disable = false
  disable_cache = false
  volumes = ["/certs/client", "/cache"]
```

And the gitlab-ci.yml:

```yaml
stages: # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - test  
test-job: # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  stage: test
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - name: registry.hub.docker.com/library/docker:24.0.2-dind-rootless
      alias: docker
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376/
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: '/certs'
  tags: [docker]
  script:
    - docker info
```

With this configuration I only get the no route to host error at the end of the job:

```bash
Server:
ERROR: error during connect: Get https://docker:2376/v1.40/info: dial tcp: lookup docker on ip.ip.ip.ip: no such host
errors pretty printing info
```

And it failed with this line:

```bash
*** WARNING: Service runner-xxxxxxxx-project-1-concurrent-0-aa807e5da65143e8-registry.hub.docker.com__library__docker-0 probably didn't start properly.
Health check error:
service "runner-xxxxxxxx-project-1-concurrent-0-xxxxxxxxx-registry.hub.docker.com__library__docker-0-wait-for-service" timeout
```

And if I try to replace the  **DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: '/certs'** **by  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ''**
The error message "is docker daemon running appear.

Can anyone help with this?